# Maximum amount of P4

Tags: stoichiometry

$\ce{2Ca3(PO4)2 +6SiO2 +10C->6CaSiO3 +P4 +10CO}$

What is the maximum amount of P4 that can be produced from 1.0 kg of phosphorite if the phosphorite sample is 75% $\ce{2Ca3(PO4)2}$ by mass

---

The wording is confusing. I do not know what to do. Would you start by finding the limiting reactant?

Answer (score 2):

First you find the number of moles of $\ce{Ca3(PO4)2}$ reacting. You have 75% of 1 kg, i.e. 750 grams, of calcium phosphate. The rest of reagents are assumed to be in excess as we have to find the maximum amount of $\ce{P4}$ obtained, hence reaction should not have other limiting reagents.